# Single user linux

Tags: linux, permissions, virtualization

I often find myself building a website with some back-end processing on a LAMP like stack. In these situations I wonder why I need all this Linux user permissions headache. I don't have any direct users (just website visitors).

It appears to me that Linux tried to be multiuser but failed/lost. A basic idea of early Linux/Unix was to make big computing resources accessible for multiple users. Nowadays this task is given to Virtualization software not the OS. It's virtually impossible to do anything in Linux without the sudo password, and even without giving out sudo passwords it's hard to guarantee privacy between users. Virtualization software, on the other hand, takes the job gloriously.

So are we stuck with some inherited mess from old times? Is it possible to strip out the whole multiuser thing? Has this been done anywhere? Is it discussed before? Would it help at all? Am I wrong in some/many ways?

Thanks for your wise comments, one rule though, it's not allowed to say "it's safer/better to,..." without any actual specific reasons to demonstrate that claim.

Comment: You want to strip them off, or just go into the "Single User Mode" which is available on almost all variants of Linux? Also if it is 100% single user, are you running your web server (and any services for that matter) as that 1 user?

Comment: What are you doing that you need `sudo` all the time? Even Windows uses multiple users for different things. Its neat to isolate permissions and the answer of gronostaj gives a good example for it.

Answer (score 3):

So you have a simple PHP application that runs with root privileges. It works well, all is fine.

One day a new PHP vulnerability is published. Before you're able to patch it, someone uses it and gains access to system shell through PHP. He initially just wants to dump your database (for user credentials) and maybe install some malicious Javascript, but then he realizes that he's root!

He adds your machine to his botnet, installs a new authentication module that will store your password on login and starts a hidden SSH server - so that he can still access the box after that PHP bug is patched. Before you realize what happened, your server password is known to the attacker and the server is hosting his doubtfully legal business's website.